# Unable to import data from Informix non transactional database to HDFS

Tags: sqoop, informix

I'am trying to import a table from an Informix DB to HDFS. I'am using Cloudera distribution. I have made sure that the jars are correctly placed under /var/lib/sqoop folder on the host where I'am running the command.

Below is the command and the error that I'am receiving.

Sqoop Command:

```
 sqoop import --connect jdbc:informix-sqli://mgomtcmsp1:50001/cms:INFORMIXSERVER=fmg_pgomtp1 \
 --username AL667RE \
 --target-dir "/data/raw/manage_agex" \
 --password Bdhuern@17892 \
 --table agex \
 --driver com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver
```

Error:

```
18/09/03 10:54:49 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: No Transaction Isolation on non-logging db's
java.sql.SQLException: No Transaction Isolation on non-logging db's
        at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:348)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.setTransactionIsolation(IfxSqliConnect.java:2012)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:910)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:763)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:786)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:289)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:260)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:246)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:327)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1858)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1657)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:494)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:621)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
18/09/03 10:54:49 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1663)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:494)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:621)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

Comment: The sqoop Java code is trying to set the transaction isolation level (setTransactionIsolation()) but your Informix database (cms) does not support transactions as it has no logging. Ask you Informix dba to change the logging mode and it should work. More info here:   http://informix.hcldoc.com/help/topic/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0661.htm